# How to use the "ThrowTerminatingError" method in cmdlet development?

Tags: powershell, error-handling, powershell-cmdlet, unhandled-exception

When handling errors in my cmdlet development, I encounter an unexpected behavior of the ThrowTerminatingError method.

Calling the method results in an unhandled exception of PipelineStoppedException. Thus, I do not get a formatted error in PowerShell, but a long unhandled exception error message.

My code corresponds to the following structure:

```
protected override async void ProcessRecord()
{
    try
    {
        var transferClient = new TransferClient(...);
        var result = await transferClient.GetAsync(); // Throws an AuthenticationException
    }
    catch (AuthenticationException exception)
    {
        var record = new ErrorRecord(exception, "TestException", ErrorCategory.AuthenticationError, null);
        ThrowTerminatingError(record); // Unhandled exception
    }
}
```

System info:

- Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK: 7.2.8
- System.Management.Automation: 7.2.8
- Target: PowerShell 7

Comment: Try to use `Cmdlet.WriteError()` instead, which I generally prefer, because it allows the caller of the cmdlet to control error handling through the common parameter `-ErrorAction`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I would like to force a termination, otherwise there would be consequential errors.